# How can I use org-mode to track time without repeating tasks?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, time-tracking

I've been using org-mode for about a year now for task and time tracking.  My main purpose is to be able manage the tasks (which are pending, which are done, when the work was done) as well as create a weekly report that summarizes my time.

I've been using a very simple approach.  I have an outline hierarchy with the month at the top, followed by the week, and then each day I build up my tasks.  I have a clock table report setup at the month level using a thisweek property so that at the end of each week I get a report that I can use for filling out my timecard.

It looks something like this:

```
* November
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 5 :block thisweek :scope tree1 :link t
#+END: clocktable    
** Nov 5 - 9
*** Nov 5
**** admin, email
     CLOCK: [2012-11-05 Mon 14:28]--[2012-11-05 Mon 16:23] =>  1:55
     CLOCK: [2012-11-05 Mon 13:31]--[2012-11-05 Mon 13:36] =>  0:05
     CLOCK: [2012-11-05 Mon 13:20]--[2012-11-05 Mon 13:22] =>  0:02
     CLOCK: [2012-11-05 Mon 09:11]--[2012-11-05 Mon 09:14] =>  0:03
     CLOCK: [2012-11-05 Mon 08:03]--[2012-11-05 Mon 08:08] =>  0:05
**** TODO Fix scrubber to work with any environment
**** DONE Remedy Training
     CLOCK: [2012-11-05 Mon 08:30]--[2012-11-05 Mon 09:11] =>  0:41
**** TODO Improve label creation parsing
**** DONE CM Deploy: 8177529
     CLOCK: [2012-11-05 Mon 08:08]--[2012-11-05 Mon 08:21] =>  0:13
```

That works ok but if tasks span a day I need to create a new task for the next day otherwise the time table doesn't get created correctly (even if move the task -- along with its recorded time -- to the next day).

Now I'm starting to look into using the agenda because it seems more powerful and more elegant but I have sort of run into the same problem -- what if I have a task scheduled for one day but I don't finish so I need to move it to the next day?

This seems like it would be a pretty common situation but I haven't found anything on SOF or the web for this.  Maybe it's so basic I'm just doing something wrong??  Even my uber-reference for practical day-to-day use of org-mode, [Organize Your Life in Plain Text](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html) doesn't seem to address this.

I'm trying to achieve two things: 1) not having to re-enter a task on multiple days if I don't finish it, and 2) get an accurate weekly report (at a daily level) that does not double-count or miscount time.

Can anyone make a suggestion?

Comment: You don't ever mention `SCHEDULED` timestamps, which are basically the feature I use the most in org, for they give me, in the agenda, a summary of all I didn't complete on previous days (and in the agenda, it's easy to shedule them to the next day when that happens). Do they help ? (Also, your question has very frightening wall-of-text looks, you'd probably get a lot more attention by summing it up. At least make a **tl;dr** and *pretty-format* the important stuff if you really need **that thorough** a description).

Comment: Thanks, Le Vieux, I will take heed of the "wall-of-text" in my next post!  I am starting to use the agenda more and I do appreciate the usefulness of scheduling/rescheduling.  But my basic problem is not being able to get a weekly breakdown in a report.